# How to load all csv files in a folder with pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a folder which has

```
Sales_December.csv
Sales_January.csv
Sales_February.csv
etc.
```

How can i make pyspark read all of them into 1 dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- create an empty list
- read your csv files one by one and append DataFrames to the list
- use `reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, <list>)` to combine them
  into one single DataFrame